# Как запустить все .exe-файлы из папки?

Tags: bat, cmd

Есть много файлов .exe в папке, из нее я запускаю батник, который должен запустить все эти файлы. Как сделать?

Comment: @ttt111, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Вот пример поочередного запуска *.exe через цикл for в каталоге диска C:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
%~d0
for /r C:\ %%i in (*.exe) do start /wait "" "%%i"
pause
```